# Different results of \mag statement

Tags: pdftex, luatex, paper-size, magnification

The following example gives different results for pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I use a recent TeX Live 2019 installation.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\mag=250 %
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\LaTeX \hfill \LaTeX
\vfill
\LaTeX \hfill \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

1. pdfLaTeX: A page on A8 paper (53mm x 74mm)
2. LuaLaTeX: A page on A4 paper (210mm x 297mm)

I use the package »geometry« only for transfering the page size informations to the output file. Without »geometry« I get the same results. Why ist the size not changed with LuaLaTeX? Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is a documentated difference to pdftex. From the manual:

> Magnification (\mag) is only supported in dvi output mode. You can set
>   this parameter and it even works with true units till you switch to
>   pdf output mode. When you use pdf output you can best not touch the
>   \mag variable. This fuzzy behaviour is not much different from using
>   pdf backend related functionality while eventually dvi output is
>   required

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.